# rename VMware vCenter guest name via Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware-vcenter

I'm trying to find a way to rename guest vm name (not the OS ) in vsphere (vcenter Env). I've managed to create a VM using the vsphere_guest module but I cant find a way to rename the guest VM

the issue or play is like this

1. I create some VM and give thame name vi inventory file {{inventory_hostname}}
2. they boot setup linux ( kix and pxe )
3. get DHCP + DNS the dhcp is set before the play so vm can named "host1" but DNS "host4"
   and I want to change so it will be OS name = host1  and vsphere name = host1

Thanks for the help

Noam

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename a VMware guest inside vSphere using any of the official modules as of Ansible 1.9.